# How do I diagnose trouble code P0567 OBD-II in my car and what are its causes? Which component of cruise control system should be checked first?

Tags: engine, car, diagnostics, cruise-control

I am getting issue with my car's cruise control system, and while diagnosing, this code is shown, I want to know the reason and meaning of this code.

Answer (score 1):

**The P0567 code indicates that there has been a malfunction in the electrical components of the cruise control resume signal circuit, as detected by the PCM.**

**What the P0567 code means?**

This is a generic power train diagnostic trouble code (DTC) and typically applies to OBD-II vehicles equipped with cruise control. That may include but is not limited to vehicles from Peugeot, Ford, Nissan, Chevrolet, Hyundai, VW, Audi, Citroen, etc. Although generic, the exact repair steps may vary depending on year, make, and model and power train configuration.

**What is the severity of this DTC?**

Severity would be considered moderately low. Even if you lose entire functionality of the cruise control system, you can still get to work safely. As far as further damage if left unattended goes, this would be the rare case in which you may be able to neglect if let’s say, your vehicle is old and you can live without cruise, or you cannot afford to fix the vehicle. That being said, it is possible that neglecting any electrical issue long enough may result in further damage.

**Common causes of the code:**

1. Cruise control switch, or buttons within the switch, defective
2. ABS Connectors not making proper and effective electrical connection
3. Wires within the cruise control harness chafed and causing short, open, resistance, etc.
4. Cruise control switch assembly contaminated with fluid (i.e. coffee, soda, juice, etc.)
5. ECM issue
6. Cruise control module defective

**Symptoms of the code:**

1. Cruise control light in dash not coming on or constant
2. Cruise control inoperative
3. Cannot set cruise control to desired speed or speed is erratic

**How to troubleshoot the trouble code?**

**Step-1**

First visually inspect the cruise control switch. Sometimes, buttons are missing, cola has stuck the button in one position and buttons are loose and not making proper electrical connections. That all said make sure that the buttons that control the cruise functions, are freely moving and not contaminated with potentially damaging particles or dirt.

**Step-2**

Does the cruise control light come on in the instrument cluster when cruise is manually activated? If not, you may want to verify if there is a fuse for the circuit. This information should be found in the service manual.

**Step-3**

To pin point the specific wire involved in the fault, you will definitely need a proper wiring harness for your vehicle. Always acquire proper service information before executing anything too invasive.

**Step -4**

It is a good idea to make sure your ABS system is in good working order and no ABS light on in the dash. ABS uses numerous sensors including speed sensors that, if malfunctioning, could fool the computers into thinking the vehicle is going faster or slower than the actual speed.